# chrony immediate time sync

Tags: synchronization, chrony

Running RHEL-8.9 I have a handful+ servers in a computer lab, which do not have an internet connection and [currently] have no means of fetching any kind of stratum-0 type time.  We therefore manually set time in linux to local time on one sever which is good enough, and the server bios/efi clock is set to UTC.

I am having issues getting other servers to time sync, if I manually do a `date` on each simultaneously they are 60+ seconds off and I am getting frustrated with this not working.  If anyone is so inclined can you describe in as short as possible the process [which should be simple?] to do the following?

- Server @ 192.168.1.1  I have made my time server

  - `firewalld` port 123-udp and 323-udp is open
  - `/etc/chronyd.conf`

    - has no `server` line, because it does not fetch a time
    - has `allow 192.168.1.0/24`
    - has `local stratum 10`
- Servers @ 192.168.1.x

  - `/etc/chrony.conf` has `server 192.168.1.1 iburst maxpoll 10`
  - rest of chrony.conf is whatever is the default from a clean install from rhel-8.9-x86_64-dvd.iso; everything else basically commented out

**How can I immediately time sync in linux**, on a new server having a clean install from rhel-8.9.iso where its clock is however many minutes off from my 192.168.1.1 server?  So I don't care how far off the time is and I do not expect any software to break as it's a clean install with only me ssh'ing in as root at this point in time.

And what is the simplest way to check that `chrony` is working a [client] system that it can connect to a time server and that it *will* time sync?  And if my clock if off 45 seconds how do I know when it will be sync'd ?  What can I look at that will give me confidence that when I check an hour later or tomorrow that the time will be sync'd, rather than coming back each day for a week finding no time sync.